# sqlite3 view() prints with empty list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, function, sqlite

I have testtable() function that works to create the table if necessary and list all the PDF file names in a column. However, when I execute my view() function, it prints an empty list. Am I missing something or just going about this in the wrong way?

```
import os, sys
import sqlite3
import csv

testdb = 'pdftestdir.db'

def testtable():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(testdb)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test (name TEXT)')
    path = os.listdir('/root/Desktop/PDF')
    conn = sqlite3.connect(testdb)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test')
    exists = cur.fetchall()
    for name in path:
        if name.endswith('.pdf'):
            if not exists:
                cur.execute('INSERT INTO test VALUES (?)', (name,))
            else:
                pass
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()

def view():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(testdb)
    cur = conn.cursor()
    cur.execute('SELECT * FROM test')
    cur.fetchall()
    rows = cur.fetchall()
    conn.close()
    print(rows)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You unnecessarily call `cur.fetchall()` without storing the returning value to a variable, and the cursor has already reached the end of the rows returned with that call, so the second time you call `cur.fetchall()` it no longer has any more rows to return.

You can fix this by simply removing the redundant call.

Change:

```
cur.fetchall()
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

to:

```
rows = cur.fetchall()
```

Comment: I don't know how I missed that when I was looking it over. Thanks. That fixed it with ease.